# how to put multiple background to a button without conflict with css

Tags: html, css

I have a 3D button with different background styles.  I want to set a small icon to it. But some ways it wont show and other ways the background colors changes or disappears

```css
.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px;
  width:170px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top:15px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  /*
  Kinda replicates keyline but looks dumb.
  @include filter(
    drop-shadow(0 1px 0 rgba(blue, 0.2))
    drop-shadow(0 -1px 0 rgba(blue, 0.2))
  );
  */
}
.button.blue {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a2d3e9, #7abedf);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a2d3e9, #7abedf);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a2d3e9, #7abedf) ; 
     
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 1px #6fadcb, 0px 1px 1px #54809d, -2px 1px 1px #6fadcb, -1px 2px 1px #54809d, -3px 2px 1px #6fadcb, -2px 3px 1px #54809d, -4px 3px 1px #6fadcb, -3px 4px 1px #54809d, -5px 4px 1px #6fadcb, -4px 5px 1px #54809d, -6px 5px 1px #6fadcb, -6px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -3px 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), -2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), -1px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 1px 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 2px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 3px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 4px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 5px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 6px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), inset 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.button.yellow {

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2d851, #ecc92b);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2d851, #ecc92b);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2d851, #ecc92b);
   
  color: black;
  text-shadow: -2px 2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -1px 0px 1px #d9b826, 0px 1px 1px #b1961d, -2px 1px 1px #d9b826, -1px 2px 1px #b1961d, -3px 2px 1px #d9b826, -2px 3px 1px #b1961d, -4px 3px 1px #d9b826, -3px 4px 1px #b1961d, -5px 4px 1px #d9b826, -4px 5px 1px #b1961d, -6px 5px 1px #d9b826, -6px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -3px 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), -2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), -1px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 1px 13px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 2px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 3px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 4px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 5px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), 6px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01), inset 0 4px 5px -2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.button.yellow:after, .button.yellow:before {
  background: black;
}
.button.yellow:after {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4));
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4));
}
.button.yellow:before {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 -2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 -2px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35));
}
.button.yellow .arrow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4));
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4));
}
.button:active  {
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-6px, 6px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-6px, 6px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-6px, 6px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-6px, 6px, 0);
}
.button .arrow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}
.button:after {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}
.button:after, .button:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  right: 15px;
  top: 14px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 18px;
  background: white;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}
.button:before {
  height: 14px;
  top: 26px;
  right: 16px;
  z-index: 3;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-137deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-137deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-137deg);
  transform: rotate(-137deg);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15));
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="button blue" onclick="javascript:onKeyPress('B')">CARDLESS<br></a>
    <a href="#" class="button yellow">VIDEO CONFERANCE<br></a>
</div>
```

when i add background: url(); 
to .button.blue {}
if i add it before the last background nothing happens 
if i add it after it  , the background color disappear and the image appear

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(122, 122, 126, 1), rgba(122, 122, 126, 0.65) ), url(../images/bg/bg10.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

i added  this to html and it worked

```
<div class="" style="height:13%;width:100%;bottom:0;left:0;position:absolute;opacity:1;background-color:Silver;z-index:1000">
    <div class="row">
     <a href="#" class="button blue" onclick="javascript:onKeyPress('B')">
         <img src="images/gesture.png" style="position:absolute;right:50;width:50px;height:50px;top:02;background-color:" alt="">CARDLESS<br>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="button yellow"  >
     <img src="images/call.png" style="position:absolute;right:50;width:50px;height:50px;top:02;background-color:" alt="">  VIDEO CONFERANCE<br>
    </a>
</div>
```